# Calculate true percentage of video watch by user using sql

Tags: sql, percentage

| user_id | ts | url | event_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1473811200 | /home | page_view |
| 12345 | 1473811205 | /home | link_click |
| 12345 | 1473811215 | /video | page_view |
| 12345 | 1473811220 | /video | click_video_play |
| 12345 | 1473811225 | /video | video_play_5_pct |
| 12345 | 1473811230 | /video | video_play_10_pct |
| 12345 | 1473811235 | /video | video_play_15_pct |
| 12345 | 1473811236 | /video | scroll |
| 12345 | 1473811240 | /video | video_play_20_pct |
| 12345 | 1473811245 | /video | video_play_25_pct |
| 12345 | 1473811247 | /video | scroll |
| 12345 | 1473811250 | /video | video_play_30_pct |

From this sample output above, we can follow user 12345’s journey on our website:

- 12345 lands on `/home`
- They click on a link that directs them to `/video`
- They click on the video play button on `/video`
- The video starts to play on the page
- The video continues to play until...

  - 12345 scrolls down the page (let’s assume all ‘scroll’ events cause a user to scroll far enough down the page that they can no longer physically see the video)
- The video continues to play in the background even after the scroll event
- Another scroll event occurs (we do not know if they can know see the video again, but for the purpose of this exercise this is not important)

The problem with our existing logging systems is that we end up overstating how much of the video a user actually “physically” watched.

For example, the sample output indicates that user 12345 watched at least 30% of the video. However, we know that they scrolled past the video after only watching the first 15%, so we should mark pct_video_watched as 15%.

I tried case when to get the timestamp of video_click and scroll and I am thinking of adding a variable that will calculate the total length of the video so I can get percentage by taking scroll event timestamp / video length * 100 but I don't know how to calculate that using given information

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And don't forget to add a tag for the dbms you're using.